# Change data types for multiple columns R

Tags: r

I'm trying to change data types of the columns but in vain,what's wrong?

```
newtibble_1 <- newtibble_1 %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
  lapply(.[1:7],as.character)
```

Comment: `newtibble_1[1:7] <- lapply(newtibble_1[1:7], as.character)` ?

Comment: AFter the type.convert i.e. `%>% mutate_at(1:7, as.character)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `dplyr`, the syntax would be to use `mutate_at`

```
library(dplyr)
newtibble_1 <- newtibble_1 %>%
                 type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
                 mutate_at(1:7, as.character)
```

---

The output of `lapply`is a `list` and may not be the one OP wanted.  In the above code, the issue is in containerizing or blocking the code as there are a lot of things happening i.e. extracting the first 7 columns, then looping with  `lapply` etc..

It can be done with `{}`.

```
mtcars %>% 
       {lapply(.[1:7], as.character)}
```

Or if we need to do this in pipe, then first do the extraction and then loop

```
mtcars %>%
      .[1:7] %>%
      lapply(as.character)
```

But, note that both the above will select the columns 1:7 and is not updating the original dataset columns.  For that we may need to do the `<-` to the same selected columns

---

Or another option is `map`

```
library(purrr)
mtcars %>%
     map_at(1:7, as.character) %>%
     bind_cols
```

Comment: Ok, 2 more questions: I use mutate to change 2 column's type and it doesn't work: `data_tibble_1 <- data_tibble %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(Order_TMS_1 = as.character(Order_TMS_1),
         Cbm = as.numeric(str_replace(CBM,",","."))`. Type won't change. Second question is what gives this code: `type.convert(as.is = TRUE)`

Comment: @Muska the `type.convert` is applied on all character columns and change it to specified type based on the inherent type. i.e. `type.convert(c('1.2', '1.3', '1.5')) changes it to numeric while `type.convert(c('A', 'B'), as.is = TRUE)` converts to `character` (if we don't specify as.is = TRUE, it converts to `factor`

Comment: @Muska If the `type.convert` is not changing the type, it means that column have sssome elements that doesn't match i.e. `type.convert(c('1.2', '1.3', 'A'), as.is = TRUE)` will sstill be `character` because there is a letter in it  and it is evaluated based on hierarchy

Comment: Thank you, now I understand!